# Finding formula from given table

Tags: analysis

I'm sucks at finding formula, can you guys help me? As we can see below, there is a table with x, y, z, and i values. My question, what is formula to get the value of i, if the values of x, y, z are given?

| x | y | z | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 275 | 50 | 137,50 |
| 2 | 275 | 50 | 206,25 |
| 5 | 275 | 50 | 247,50 |

I thought the formula as simple as

> y-(y*(z/100))

but the formula only apply for first row data, looks like it should involve x value somewhere,  I don't know how

Comment: This is far too little data. For example, we cannot determine the role of $y,z$ in the formula since their values in the 3 data are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your math teacher was trying to be too clever. The simplest formula is just:

$137.50 * (1+\frac{x-1}{x})$

No need to use $y$ or $z$.

Comment: thanks, I have enlightenment

i = (y-(y*(z/100)))*(1+((x-1)/x))